# C# Array Calculate Grades

Tags: c#, arrays

Appreciate the help. I am entirely new with C# although I took an Intro Course, we were presented by our instructor to solve this. I am trying to calculate a grade array w/ maximum of 10 in which I need to find the lowest grade, disregard the lowest and then print out the letter grade. I managed to get the way to calculate the elements of arrays through a third party which I have input in the "Overall Calculation" block. The results are way out of whack at the moment but Im not quite sure where to troubleshoot the problem.

```
        const int MAX_SIZE = 10;

    decimal[] quizList = new decimal[MAX_SIZE]; // Array of 10 decimals.

    // Add to List of quiz
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add grade data to array.
        quizList[count] = Convert.ToInt32(txtList.Text);
        count++;
        quizTotal += quizList[count];
        DisplayProducts();
        FindLowest(quizList, count); // Locate lowest and print out to user.
        if (count == MAX_SIZE) // no more space.
        {
            txtList.Enabled = false;
            btnAdd.Enabled = false;
        }
        txtList.Text = ""; // clear input as soon as user enters data (clarity/convenience purposes)
        txtList.Focus();
    }

    private void DisplayProducts()
    {
        string gradeList;
        lstGrades.Items.Clear(); // Erase list grades.
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            gradeList = quizList[i].ToString();
            lstGrades.Items.Add(gradeList);
        }
    }

    public decimal FindLowest(decimal[] q, int s)
    {
        decimal smallest = quizList[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            if (quizList[i] < smallest)
            {
                smallest = quizList[i];
            }
            txtLowest.Text = Convert.ToString(smallest);
        }
        return smallest;
    }

    //Overall Calculation 
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        // Calculate each quiz (
        for (int i = 0; i < quizList.Length; i++)
        {
            decimal resultQuiz;

            // Conversion to specified percentages
            resultQuiz = quizList[i] * Convert.ToDecimal(0.15);
            midTerm = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMidterm.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(0.30);
            finalExam = Convert.ToDecimal(txtFinalEx.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(0.40);



            // Calculated Total
            totalGrade = resultQuiz + midTerm + finalExam;
        }

        decimal lowestGrade = FindLowest(quizList, count);

        // Get average without lowest grade.
        average = totalGrade - lowestGrade;

        //Print out Average.
        txtAverage.Text = Convert.ToString(average);

        // Conversion to letter grade based upon percentage.
        if (average >= 90)
        {
            txtLetter.Text = "A";
        }
        else if (average >= 80 && average <= 90)
        {
            txtLetter.Text = "B";
        }
        else if (average >= 70 && average <= 80)
        {
            txtLetter.Text = "C";
        }
        else if (average >= 60 && average <= 70)
        {
            txtLetter.Text = "D";
        }
        else
        {
            txtLetter.Text = "F";
        }
    }
```

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This code seems to have a number of problems.  First, your `totalGrade` variable is overwritten each time through your loop, so you aren't really getting an average of every number in your `quizList` array.  Second, you are looking for an average, but I don't see division anywhere in your code.  Also, subtracting the lowest grade from a result that already seems to be weighted is going to skew your data.  That's just bad math.  There's more, but I'm out of characters.  I think it suffices to say you need to spend some time with your debugger stepping through this code to see what's going on.

Comment: Pretty much what @ScoobyDrew18 said. Additionally, are you locked into doing it this way or are you allowed to use Linq queries? It would require some sql-"ish" filtering of the quizList, but it would reduce the code by a decent amount. 
With what you currently have, a tip: account for the lowest score omitting before/within loop. As it is an assignment, I'm hesitant to do/say anything more.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have no background with programming before this so when I was presented this as my first project, it was daunting however I did what i could to make due. I'll do what I can with your inputs.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is [learn how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @DourHighArch Thank you for the link. I agree that if Im to be a great programmer - thats a must.